# JSON Path Extraction

Tags: json, path, extract

I have JSON Data which has an Array Element by the name of "References" . 
This "References" array further has elements like TypeName , Id and an element Called Attributes which further has elements like name and type.
possible values for TypeName are Employees , Offices , Hardware etc

```
"References": [
        {
          "TypeName": "Employees",
          "Attributes": {
            "Type": "9t59c6ghn1l4y81nvu7a",
            "Name": "WH-3",
                }
        },
        {
          "TypeName": "Hardware",
          "Attributes": {
            "Name": "rz2j8c85kbl3add5vmb5",
                      }
        },
        {
          "TypeName": "Organization",

          "Attributes": {
            "Type": "4qww1im1o6w4xm4ehlkm",
            "Name": "Training"
          }
        },
]
```

I want to extract the path for the element TypeName of the array "References".
e.g: I want to extract the path for TypeName Organization and further for Attributes of that TypeName.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract the Organization Attributes however your JSON isn't valid JSON, so you'll need to fix that first depending on how forgiving the parser is that you are using.  The whole document needs to have an object or array at the root, and there are extra commas after the last properties of some objects in the document.  Here is a fixed document:

```
{
    "References": [
        {
            "TypeName": "Employees",
            "Attributes": {
                "Type": "9t59c6ghn1l4y81nvu7a",
                "Name": "WH-3"
            }
        },
        {
            "TypeName": "Hardware",
            "Attributes": {
                "Name": "rz2j8c85kbl3add5vmb5"
            }
        },
        {
            "TypeName": "Organization",
            "Attributes": {
                "Type": "4qww1im1o6w4xm4ehlkm",
                "Name": "Training"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get the Organization Attributes you can then use the following JSON Path

```
$..References[?(@.TypeName=='Organization')].Attributes
```

I have tested this using the online JSON query tool here: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathwhereselect